# How to save an array for each run of 'for loop'?

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, python-xarray

I have ocean temperature data having 'depth' and 'time', as data(depth,time).
I want to use the 'detrend' function at each depth and save that result. So that I get as a result detrend(number of depth, time) as a one array. Depth = 42 and time = 72

for i in range(44):
depth = temp[:,i]
detrend = s.detrend(depth)

But, this is giving only last depth value calculation.

Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using `scipy.signal.detrend()`, you can use the `axis` argument to do this without a loop. It's unclear to me which axis you're hoping to detrend, but you can pick `axis=0` or `axis=1` depending on which you want. So:

```
detrend = s.detrend(temp,axis=0)
```

In general, if you do want to do something like this in a loop you could create an empty array of the right size that you then write into in each iteration of the loop.

```
detrended = np.zeros_like(temp)
for i in range(44):
    depth = temp[:,i]
    detrended[:,i] = s.detrend(depth)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, if you don't save the detrended data in a list or an array during the for loop it is obvious that only the last `detrend` will survive. Actually there is no need to use a for loop for that.

Instead of using scipy methods you can use also directly use the xarray [`polyfit`](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.Dataset.polyfit.html) and [`polyval`](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.polyval.html) method, which let you specify the dimension over which to detrend.

Example:

```
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr

#test data with linear trend
data_vars=np.arange(1000)[None,:]+np.random.randn(50,1000)*100
data=xr.DataArray(data_vars,dims=['depth','time'])

p = data.polyfit(dim='time', deg=1)
fit = xr.polyval(data['time'], p.polyfit_coefficients)
detrend = data-fit

#eg for zeroth depth
data.isel(depth=0).plot(label='raw')
detrend.isel(depth=0).plot(label='lin. detrended')
plt.legend()
```

[image: Plotted detrended data]